# Может ли флаттер работать тесно с виндой?

Tags: flutter, dart

Появилась такая задача: приложение на флаттер берет какую-то папку или файл и просматривает группы пользователей, для которых эта папка/файл видна

Что-то подобное может реализовать флаттер приложение?

Comment: библиотеку на си придется писать. можно

Comment: @eri - спасибо, а вы случайно не знаете каких-нибудь статей по написанию подобных вещей?

Comment: @eri - еще судя по профилю, я понял, что вы работали с django. Не могли бы подсказать, стоит ли писать апишку на нем или лучше выбрать какой-нибудь другой язык и фреймворк?

Comment: если нужна админка - то однозначно. если данными рулить только по апи, то можно обойтись без него

Comment: @eri - а какая разница между админкой и рулежкой данных в джанго? Я думаю, что как-то неправильно вас понял

Comment: из плюсов джанго: админка полуавтоматическая, миграции. из минусов: синхронная обработка запросов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте через вот этот комбаин на WIN32. Вроде есть вызовы к файловой системе.

https://pub.dev/packages/win32

Если интересует всего несколько операций с виндовс, то я бы написал свой модуль. Читайте по запросу связанное с [Dart FFI](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/c-interop)

Comment: Да, я видел эту либу. Немного не понял отличия от стандартной библиотеки ```path_provider```, потому что и там, и там вроде функционал чтения, записи и открытия одинаков (это что касаемо работы с файловой системой)

Comment: надо глубже смотреть.